# Filter a pandas column using regex within the header

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I'm reading in an Excel file to a Pandas data frame but one of the column headers has loads of comments in. It has a keyword 'Measure' amongst all this text which is specific to only this one header. Within the 'contains', how would I filter any header that simply has the keyword 'Measure' somewhere within the header?

The following code is filtering my data frame based 3 filters, but the third filter I just want it to identify the column itself that includes the text 'measure' opposed to having to write it as 'hereisallthe randomtextmeasure'

```
filtered = df[(df['Mode'].isin(mode_filter)) & (df['Level'].isin(level_filter)) & (df['hereisalltherandomtextmeasure'].isin(measure_filter))]
```

The reason I'm trying to do this is because I'm running the same code on multiple files but the 'measure' column changes for each file.

First file:

```
Mode | Level | hereisalltherandomtextmeasure
```

Second file:

```
Mode | Level | hereismorerandomtextmeasure
```

The only static thing about them is that they contain the word measure so ideally I'd like to identify the column that simply contains the word measure opposed to applying a full string.

Thanks.

Comment: Sorry what are you asking here? To find the column or to filter it out?

Comment: Sorry, I want to simply identify the column that contains the text 'Measure' in it, which I then apply the filter measure_filter too using .isnin.

Comment: Then just `df.columns[df.columns.str.contains('hereisall the random textMeasure')]` will return you that column

Comment: I want to ignore the text in front of 'Measure' as depending on what file I load in, this is different each time. So as long as the column header contains 'Measure, then my code will filter on it.

Comment: Can you provide some example strings and what exactly you want to match?

Comment: So you just want to find any column with 'measure' in it irrespective of where it is? in your example Measure is preceded with text will it always have some random letters before Measure?

Comment: I don't understand how my answer doesn't answer your query about the 3rd column name containing the word 'Measure' you question is terribly unclear you need to post raw data, code, representative df and desired output

Comment: Sorry for not being as clear cut, I've attempted to update my question to be more concise. I'm wanting to apply the logic to just identify the word 'measure' within the following code `(df['hereisalltherandomtextmeasure'].isin(measure_filter))`

Comment: I don't understand the point of using the filter `& (df['hereisalltherandomtextmeasure'].isin(measure_filter))` or even my answer in your code. By adding this as a boolean condition it's meaningless as your intention is to just find that column that is different to filter the df based on the content of the df itself

Comment: My intention is to find the column and then filter it after the column has been found...

Comment: Then you can use my code to identify the column and pass this, I don't understand what more you're after

Answer (score 1):

IIUC then you can use [`str.contains`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.contains.html#pandas.Series.str.contains) to find if your matching string is contained anywhere in the columns:

```
In [7]:
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['hereisall the random textMeasure', 'Measurement', 'asdasds'])
df.columns[df.columns.str.contains('Measure')]

Out[7]:
Index(['hereisall the random textMeasure', 'Measurement'], dtype='object')
```

Comment: Hi Ed, thanks for the answer. I have the following code that filters my dataframe on 3 filters: `filtered = df[(df['Mode'].isin(mode_filter)) & (df['Level'].isin(level_filter)) & (df['hereisall the random textMeasure'].isin(measure_filter))]`. So how would the last part incorporate the str.contains element to just search for 'measure'?

Comment: Rather than post little snippets of additional information, can you edit you question with all the necessary information, SO is a Q+A site, not a forum. Your question should have enough information so we should not need to ask many questions to seek clarification